# A question in Fontaine--Laffaille theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, galois-representations

Let $K$ be finite unramified extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ with ring of integers $W$. Let ${\rm MF}$ be the category of strongly divisible $W$-modules $M$ with ${\rm Fil}^0M=M$ and ${\rm Fil}^{p-1}M=0$.  Let ${\rm Crys}(G_K)$ be the category of finite free $\mathbf{Z_p}$-representations of $G_K$ which become crystalline over $\mathbf{Q}_p$.  There is a functor
$$A:{\rm MF} \to {\rm Crys}(G_K), \qquad M \mapsto {\rm Hom}(M, A_{\rm crys}),$$
where the ${\rm Hom}'s$ are required to preserve the filtration and the Frobenius action, which is fully faithful by Fontaine-Laffaille theory.

Given $T$ in the image of the above functor, one can construct a finite free $W$-module with filtration and Frobenius, namely $B(T)={\rm Hom}_{G_K}(T, A_{\rm crys})$. Note that $B(A(M))[1/p]$ is isomorphic to $M[1/p]$ by the theory of crystalline representations. I believe that $B$ is not the inverse to $A$ in general, however.

Questions: 1) What is an example of a $T$ for which $B(T)$ is not the strongly divisible module associated to $T$?  2) For which $T$ is $B(T)$ the strongly divisible lattice associated to $T$?